# How to show elements using jQuery based on data attributes

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to show certain elements in a list based on matching data attribute values.

For example :

```
<ul>

    <li data-album-id-trigger="1" class="album-trigger">Show / Hide album</li>
    <ul data-album-id="1" class="album-list" style="display:none">
        <li>Track 1</li>
        <li>Track 2</li>
        <li>Track 3</li>
    </ul>

    <li data-album-id-trigger="2" class="album-trigger">Show / Hide album</li>
    <ul data-album-id="2" class="album-list" style="display:none">
        <li>Track 1</li>
        <li>Track 2</li>
        <li>Track 3</li>
    </ul>

</ul>
```

So basically, when you click the `.album-trigger` element with a `data-album-id-trigger` value of 1, the `.album-list` with a `data-album-id` value of 1 will appear using the jQuery `.show()` method.

Any help would be great.

Comment: FYI, this isn't valid HTML markup, UL cannot be direct child of other UL, wrap it in LI. Now regarding your issue, what have you tried?

Comment: where is your jQuery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
//click handler for album-trigger
$('.album-trigger').click(function() {
  //get the value of data-album-id-trigger
  var tid = $(this).data('album-id-trigger');
  //hide all album-list then show only the one's with data-album-id same as the clicked value
  var $current = $('.album-list[data-album-id="' + tid + '"]').toggle();
  $('.album-list').not($current).hide()

  //if you don't want to hide the previous items
  //$('.album-list[data-album-id="' + tid + '"]').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li data-album-id-trigger="1" class="album-trigger">Show / Hide album</li>
  <li data-album-id="1" class="album-list" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li>Track 1</li>
      <li>Track 2</li>
      <li>Track 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li data-album-id-trigger="2" class="album-trigger">Show / Hide album</li>
  <li data-album-id="2" class="album-list" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li>Track 1</li>
      <li>Track 2</li>
      <li>Track 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```